# Assign categories to words based on similarities

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, lda

I have corpus of about 1 million documents of sentences. Let's say:-

> sentence 1: "Thrilling contest between manchester city and manchester united ends in draw"

I want to assign sentences based on categories like above message belongs to category of "sports" and again assigned it to further categories like "football" categories in sports. 
I want to categorize texts into four categories "entertainment","sports","politics","technology". 
I have used an approach of Word2vec but it can only tells the relationship between two sentences. How exactly I can do this? I don't have any predefined labelled data just only million of records.
what I really want to do something like [this](https://www.paralleldots.com/text-classification)

Comment: See my project to have some more ideas on how to achieve that https://github.com/amirouche/sensimark